# Present View: Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I'm trying to import social framework for twitter and call the view when the social button is pressed. This is my code and I'm getting "Value of type 'GameOverScene' has no member 'present'" where I'm trying to present the view.

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
                    let tweetController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)

                    tweetController?.setInitialText("I Scored \(scoreNumber) on Gone Dots! You can try by downloading Gone Dots from the app store for free")

                    self.present(tweetController, animated: true, completion: true)

                } else {

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Account", message: "Plese log into Twitter", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                        (UIAlertAction) in
                        let settingsURL = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)

                        if let url = settingsURL{
                            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
                        }

                    }))

                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: true)

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present method is a method of UIViewController, which is why you get the error. To present in a SKScene you can say this.

```
view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: true)
```

I recommend that you google how to use UIActivityViewController which is the best way to do sharing now. I even believe to have read somewhere that those old Social APIs are deprecated. 
UIActivityViewController is the way to go as its lets you share to loads of services, including 3rd party ones and you only need to use 1 API. It also means you only need 1 share button in your app instead of multiple ones.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks so much I'm using the UIActivityViewController and its working